# Unmarshal JSON String to some "Object" using MOXy

Tags: java, json, unmarshalling, moxy

I'm trying to write a method to pretty print JSON Strings, using MOXy. So what I want is to have a method like this

```
public String formatJson(String input) { ... }
```

I think the way to go is to parse the String to a generic Object (Something like a SAX-Document, or the kind), and then marshal this Object back to JSON using some formatting properties (which is not the problem :-) ).

The Problem is, when reading the JSON-String-Input, I don't have a Class to unmarshal to (as I want the method to be as generic as possible).

**[edited]** GSON and Jackson examples removed, as only MOXy is the question.

I tried this:

```
public static String toFormattedJson(final String jsonString) {
    String formatted;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { JAXBElement.class }, null);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty(MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        unmarshaller.setProperty(JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(jsonString);
        Object element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader); // Exception is thrown here
        formatted = toFormattedJson(element);
    } catch (final JAXBException e) {
        formatted = jsonString;
    }
    return formatted;
}
```

but I get an this Exception

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshallerHandler cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecord]

So how can I read an arbitrary JSON String in to a Java Object, if I don't have any Class for that specific String?

**Update**:
This is the method used to format an Object into a JSON String:

```
private static String toFormattedJson(Object obj) {
    String result;
    try (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { obj.getClass() }, null);
        final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_REDUCE_ANY_ARRAYS, false);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_MARSHAL_EMPTY_COLLECTIONS, false);
        marshaller.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, false);
        marshaller.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(obj, writer);
        writer.flush();
        result = writer.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException | IOException e) {
        result = obj.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And using now the code from below (Martin Vojtek), when I try to format

```
String jsonString = "{\"p\" : [ 1, 2, 3]}";
```

I get:

```
{
   "p" : "1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify String as the unmarshal target:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toFormattedJson("[{\"test\":true}, \"ok\", [\"inner\",1]]"));
}

public static String toFormattedJson(final String jsonString) {
    String formatted;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { JAXBElement.class }, null);
        System.out.println("jaxbContext="+jaxbContext);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        unmarshaller.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(jsonString);
        Object element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader), String.class);
        formatted = toFormattedJsonElement(element);
    } catch (final JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        formatted = jsonString;
    }
    return formatted;
}

private static String toFormattedJsonElement(Object element) {
    return "formatted: " + element;
}
```

Comment: The code works now better for me. I still have some problems with Integer-Arrays, not being mapped correctly. Just to be sure: The classes JAXBConext, JAXBContextFactory and Unmarshaller should be from which package?
javax.xml.bind or 
org.eclipse.persistenca.jaxb?

Comment: import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.MediaType;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.StringReader;

Comment: I see unmarshal of the following string "{\"p\" : [ 1, 2, 3]}" as a bug and filed bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460630 . On the other hand, I don't think it is the best idea to us MOXy for this kind of thing. You should use e.g. JSON Processing https://jsonp.java.net/download.html

Comment: JSONP, ok. As we are using jersey2 for REST services, and it uses MOXy as default JSON processor, I though using it would be a nice idea (to just use one JSON framework). For the given task we are still using jackson. But I'll take a look at JSONP. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Latest MOXy 2.6.0-M3 is using JSON-P under the hood as a Json parser/reader.